# Load dynamic swf generated by Flex 3 in a div

Tags: jquery, css, flex3, flash, load

I am trying to load the dynamic SWF file which has 100% width and height ,generatd by my flex 3 in a div. using Jquery load() function. The div wherein i am trying to load is visible for sometime but after that my SWF comes out of div and takes whole viewport area to display the SWF. I have tried to provide fixed height and width to div but no luck. I want to load that SWF file in that particular div only. Could anybody please help me with this.

Comment: What kind of code are you using to embed the SWF? A library like SWFObject? Regular `object` / `embed` HTML code? Please provide your code in the question.

Comment: Struture is very simple

$(#divID).load('sample.swf');

<div id="divID" style="height:400px;height:400px;">
&nbsp;
</div>


where sample.swf is generating dynamically and has 100% height and width.

Comment: Can you insert SWF into a div just like that using jQuery? Would jQuery handle creating all those object and embed tags? Check jQuery docs to see if this load method accepts width/height parameters and if it does, set those to explicit values (400x400). Btw, you can edit the question and add additional information there itself instead of adding it as an "answer"

Comment: Btw, your blog url (in the profile page) is misspelled as blogpsot and it redirects to a bible studies page. They bought blogpsot domain to get traffic from typos like this : clever, ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

Struture is very simple

$(#divID).load('sample.swf');

```
> <div id="divID"
> style="height:400px;height:400px;">
> &nbsp; </div>
```

where sample.swf is generating dynamically and has 100% height and width.

Comment: Please add this to the question and delete this "answer"

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if this worked at all. AFAIK, a flash/flex object needs to be inserted in the DOM in a specific way (using `<embed>` or `<object>`).

A very nice (and free) javascript component that does everything you need is **flashembed**:

http://flowplayer.org/tools/flashembed.html

Answer (score 0):

To load the generated swf file into a certain div in your page instead of occupying the whole page, follow the three steps provided bellow. But first the reason for this behavior is that the generated "AC_OETags.js" uses "document.write()" which means printing the content directly to the page. In this solution we will alter this behavior (simply by not using document.write) but using functions returns and a JQuery call instead.

1. In AC_OETags.js change the function AC_Generateobj() as follows:

   ```
   [Last line of code] : replace document.write(str); with return str;
   ```
2. In AC_OETags.js change the function AC_FL_RunContent() as follows:

   ```
   [Last line of code] : replace AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs); with return AC_Generateobj(ret.objAttrs, ret.params, ret.embedAttrs);
   ```
3. So now both functions will return the results instead of writing to the page. The last step is to assign the return of the AC_FL_RunContent call to a variable and append it to the div in your html using JQuery:

   ```
   var mediaContent = AC_FL_RunContent( ... flash required parameters... );
   $('#YOUR_DIV_ID').replaceWith(mediaContent);
   ```